# Shadow catcher with transparent background not working in render

Tags: rendering, transparency

Simple scene.  cube floating above plane, and a light source.  I have Shadow catcher turned on the plane, and in Film 'transparent' selected. can't see the shadow in viewport shading unless i am moving the scene around, then goes away. i hit render and in the render box you see the shadow, but then fades away, and image set to ping and no shadow? also...taking like 3 minutes to render....2070 RTX

[image: transparent bg, shadow caster on plane, in viewport render]

Comment: pls provide blend file...sounds weird

Comment: wanted a bright emission light on top of a shiny cheveron shape.  to put on a website. and need the shadow below it. but when using shadow catcher on the plain, it just doesn't work. I am not sure how to attach the blend file on here.? :O